# Eclipse unable to detect Android 4.0.3 Tab

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I am trying to load and debug Android 4.0.3 app from Eclipse.

However Eclipse is not detecting in the Android Device Chooser. I have already enabled USB debug mode in the tablet. The tablet is also getting detected by my PC.

I did the same with my Android 2.1 mobile which is getting detected immediately and getting displayed in Device Chooser.

Can some one point any other thing, that my resolve this and Eclipse detects my Tab.

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to Work!

The required drivers are missing and Micromax isn't officially provinding the drivers for the Funbook.

You can download hem from here: [Drivers](http://www.mediafire.com/?c041z8h54v3pd15)

Thanks to http://funbook.gizmolord.com/

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: Drivers link broken in media fire  it says files removed :(

Answer (score 1):

After connecting your device, reset the ADB process (from the command line: adb kill-server; adb start-server)

Or from the devices tab in eclipse, there is a "Restart ADB" in the last menu on the right (the upside down triangle).

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues of my device being recognized by the debugger. Try starting a AVD first and leave it running and then try your device.

Answer (score 0):

Download Google USB Drivers through SDK manager. If it doesn't work, try to download your tab's specific drivers.

Comment: I tried it, Google USB drivers is not supporting for this tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Micromax funbook. The problem is usb driver for this device is not installed. I fixed the issue by installing the device driver from Micromax funbook official website "http://www.micromaxfunbook.com/support.php"

Note: the drivers download link will be available at the bottom of the support page.

Hope this helps!